# Firebase: How expensive is it to observe a lots of nodes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an iOS app where I will have to observe a node for every contact a user has. E.g. this means observing up to 30 different nodes.

How expensive is this regarding the traffic that is caued by lots of observations instead of one big observation?

**EDIT:**

Let's assume every registered user adds new messages to:

```
- messages
    - $userId
        - $messageId
            - timestamp
            - text
```

Now a logged in user wants to retrieve the messages of all of his contacts (much like twitter):

```
let contactIds = [userId1, userId2, ...] // Array of Strings

for userId in contactIds {
    let messagesRef = self.ref.child("messages").child(userId).observe.queryLimitedToLast(100)

    messagesRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        // ...
    })
}
```

Since the app shouldn't support followers / following like twitter, this cannot be solved like the `firefeed.io` example, where every user only observes one single feed node where each one of his contacts writes to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really which two approaches you're asking to compare. Can you write both of them in minimal code snippets, instead of text?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen see updated question. :)

Comment: You can observe multiple nodes. But attaching a listener for every user someone follows sounds like a recipe for scalability problems. As you've already seen, the scaleable solution is to fan-out the data upon write, as firefeed.io does. To prevent the need for many listeners, do as we do in that example. If you don't want to follow our lead, you'll have many listeners. There aren't really a lot of other options I can think of.

Comment: What kind of scalability problems can be caused by this approach?